# Combining two functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two functions which are essentially identical. Like for line really. One is used to add users, the other is used to remove them. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this? Or should I just keep it separate.

Add User Controller Functions:

```
$scope.addUserToGroup = function (){
    userService.addUserToGroup($scope.selectedUser, $scope.selectedAvailableGroups, $scope.assignedGroups, $scope.availableGroups,$scope.groups);
};
```

Add User Service Function:

```
  var addUserToGroup = function (selectedUser, selectedAvailableGroups, assignedGroups, availableGroups){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var addPromise = [];
    var selectLength = selectedAvailableGroups.length;

    //Add user to selected groups on server
    deferred.promise
      .then(function (){
        for (var i = 0; i < selectLength; i++){
          addPromise[i] = $().SPServices({
            operation: "AddUserToGroup",
            groupName: selectedAvailableGroups[i].name,
            userLoginName: selectedUser.domain
          });      
        };
      })
      .then(function (){
          //when promise finished, push changes to availableGroups
          for (var i = 0; i < selectLength; i++){
            assignedGroups.push(selectedAvailableGroups[i]);
            //compare groups
          };
      })
      .then(function(){
          alert(selectedUser.name + " added to: " + JSON.stringify(selectedAvailableGroups));             
      })
    //Run
    deferred.resolve();
  }
```

Remove User Controller Function:

```
    $scope.removeUserFromGroup = function (){
        userService.removeUserFromGroup($scope.selectedUser,$scope.selectedAssignedGroups, $scope.availableGroups, $scope.assignedGroups)
    };
```

Remove User Service Function:

```
  var removeUserFromGroup = function (selectedUser,selectedAssignedGroups, availableGroups, assignedGroups){
    var deferred = $q.defer();  

    var removePromise = [];
    var selectLength = selectedAssignedGroups.length;

    //Remove user from selected groups on server
    deferred.promise
      .then(function (){
        for (var i = 0; i < selectLength; i++){
          removePromise[i] = $().SPServices({
            operation: "RemoveUserFromGroup",
            groupName: selectedAssignedGroups[i].name,
            userLoginName: selectedUser.domain
          });      
        };      
      })
      .then(function (){
        //when promise finished, push changes to availableGroups
        for (var i = 0; i < selectLength; i++){
          availableGroups.push(selectedAssignedGroups[i]);
          //compare groups
        };
      })
      .then(function (){
        alert(selectedUser.name + " removed from: " + JSON.stringify(selectedAssignedGroups));  
      })
    //Run
    deferred.resolve();
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="moveButtons" >
    <button type="button" ng-disabled="!selectedUser" ng-click="addUserToGroup()">Add User</button>
    <button type="button" ng-disabled="!selectedUser" ng-click="removeUserFromGroup()">Remove</button>
</div>
```

**Also on a side note: I'm passing like 4 arguments into these functions each. It seems like a  lot. Is this the best way to do it? I feel like it might make things easier if I combined all my $scope variables into an object and simply passed the object into the function, would that make more sense?**

Comment: Pass `operation` and the alert text as a parameter?

Comment: I don't think that alone would work. Since for example the arrays I'm using in each function differ between available and assigned groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? The add parameter is a bool.

```
var handleUser = function (add, selectedUser, selectedGroups, groups){
  var deferred = $q.defer();  

  var removePromise = [];
  var selectLength = selectedAssignedGroups.length;
  var operation = add ? "AddUserToGroup" : "RemoveUserFromGroup";

  //Remove user from selected groups on server
  deferred.promise
    .then(function (){
      for (var i = 0; i < selectLength; i++){
        removePromise[i] = $().SPServices({
          operation: operation,
          groupName: selectedGroups[i].name,
          userLoginName: selectedUser.domain
        });      
      };      
    })
    .then(function (){
      //when promise finished, push changes to availableGroups
      for (var i = 0; i < selectLength; i++){
        groups.push(selectedGroups[i]);
        //compare groups
      };
    })
    .then(function (){
      var text = add ? "added to: " : "removed from: ";
      alert(selectedUser.name + text + JSON.stringify(selectedGroups));  
    })
  //Run
  deferred.resolve();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this section "var operation = add ?" are you checking if the argument exists or if it's a string === to "add"?  If I tried calling the function as such: groupService.handleUser(remove,$scope.selectedUser,$scope.selectedAssignedGroups) I'm not sure what I would get.

Comment: @Batman, add is a Boolean value referring to whether you are adding (true), or removing (false). It says if add is true, your operation is addUserToGroup.

Comment: Oooooh, okay so when I'm calling the function I'd something like handleUser(true, selectedUser, selectedGroups)?

Comment: brilliant, thanks for this, should really help me reduce the amount of code I'm writing.

Answer (score 1):

To make your code more DRY (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) I would suggest passing the operation as a parameter. I would also pass all the parameters as an object to avoid the confusion of having to remember which order the parameters are supposed to be in. Hope this helps:

```
var performOperationOnUserInGroup = function (options) {
  var operation = options.operation;
  var selectedUser = options.selectedUser;
  var selectedAssignedGroups = options.selectedAssignedGroups;
  var availableGroups = options.availableGroups;
  var assignedGroups = options.assignedGroups;

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  var addPromise = [];
  var selectLength = selectedAvailableGroups.length;

  //Add user to selected groups on server
  deferred.promise
    .then(function (){
      for (var i = 0; i < selectLength; i++){
        addPromise[i] = $().SPServices({
          operation: operation,
          groupName: selectedAvailableGroups[i].name,
          userLoginName: selectedUser.domain
        });      
      };
    })
    .then(function (){
        //when promise finished, push changes to availableGroups
        for (var i = 0; i < selectLength; i++){
          assignedGroups.push(selectedAvailableGroups[i]);
          //compare groups
        };
    })
    .then(function(){
      var action = operation === "AddUserToGroup" ? " added to: " :
                   operation === "RemoveUserFromGroup" ? "removed from: " :
                   " modified in: "; // Or throw error.
      alert(selectedUser.name + action + JSON.stringify(selectedAvailableGroups));         
    })
  //Run
  deferred.resolve();
}
```

Comment: And I guess options would be an object in my controller with all the objects that should be configured in the service?

Comment: Actually, you could just pass $scope directly to performOperationOnGroup since it has all the right properties.